# How to call destroy on disabled jquery widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-widgets, jquery-events

Used libraries: `jquery-ui-1.9.1` and `jquery-1.8.2`

I have one widget with some function called from `destroy`

```
$.widget("my.customwidget", {

    options: {

    },

    _destroy: function () {
        var self = this;

        this._super();
        //some usefull functionality
    },

    //some other declarations
});
```

If my widget was disabled, due to code in jquery-ui destroy method is not called (code from jquery-ui):

```
function handlerProxy() {
    // allow widgets to customize the disabled handling
    // - disabled as an array instead of boolean
    // - disabled class as method for disabling individual parts
    if ( instance.options.disabled === true || $( this ).hasClass( "ui-state-disabled" ) ) {
        return;
    }
    return ( typeof handler === "string" ? instance[ handler ] : handler )
                    .apply( instance, arguments );
            }
```

this `handleProxy` is inside of `_on` function. The callStack looks like so:
When element with my widget is removed, `$.cleanData` is called. Than `cleanData` calls `$( elem ).triggerHandler( "remove" )`and trigger calls `_on` for `remove` event. Than remove calls `$.widget.destroy`

How can I make call to destroy function even on disabled widget?

**UPDATE**: Created jsFiddle for demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/9yygj1wm/

**UPDATE**: This is fixed in `jquery-ui-1.9.2`, but how it can be fixed without upgrading of a library?

Comment: It is called by loading new partial view and destroying the old one with widget, so I cannot check for widgets each time when I'm reloading any part of page.

Comment: Actually, if widget is disabled _destroy method is still invoked, it wouldn't work properly otherwise. I assume something else is preventing your functionality from running.

Comment: Hm, you are right. Can you tell me where could I look?

Comment: Nope, you are wrong))

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle

Comment: in your fiddle, I change remove() for simpleWidget("destroy") and it seems to work.... http://jsfiddle.net/9yygj1wm/1/ .  Note that remove() is not the same that destroy(). destroy removes and makes other tasks commonly

Comment: remove calls events for working, but simpleWidget("destroy") calls destroy method directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I dont know indepth flow, But as per my brute force I found this was solve the issue

```
$("#destroyWidget").click(function () {
    $("a").simpleWidget("enable");
    $("a").remove();

});
```

use this for temporary, experts will explain  :)